# How can use delegate for show ViewController in the MainStoryboard from vc in other Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, storyboard

I have 2 storyboard: `MainStoryboard` and `LoginStoryboard`. I want use delegate in `LoginViewController` inside the 2 storyboard. When I tap the Login Button in `LoginViewController` I want to call the delegate and show a particular `UIViewController` in `main.storyboard` named `ProfileViewController`.

This is my class:

`LoginDelegate.swift` -> Delegate

`LoginViewController.swift` -> it is the initial vc in the LoginStoryboard

`HomeViewController.swift` -> it is the initial vc in the MainStoryboard

`ProfileViewController.swift` -> it is a vc in the MainStoryBoard that I want show next I tap Login Button

Can you help me?

Comment: better look at this https://medium.com/swift2go/passing-data-between-viewcontrollers-via-delegate-protocols-4ecde4b167de

Comment: it's interesting, but how can I set the segue identifier if two view controllers stay in different storyboard?

Comment: explain more what you actually want to do So i can help

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a `Storyboard Reference` in your `Login.storyboard` like this:

[image]

Then, reference your `main.storyboard`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this lines in Login Button Action:

```
let kMainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let profileVC = kMainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your profile VC storyboard identifier") as? ProfileViewController {
        let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileVC)
        self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```